# Store data in a var to use in REST API routes as params before running frisby tests

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jasmine, frisby.js

I have routes that use parameters (email and token) and I want to pass them in frisby tests, but before running the tests I have to get those data in my DB (mongo).

The problem is that my tests run(or not) before I get the data.

Here's the code:

```js
/* global require */
"use strict";

var frisby = require('frisby');

var emailUser;
var tokenUser;

var getDataUser = function(e) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/virtusBack-end', function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected to Database");
        var user = db.collection('users').findOne({
            name: "virtus-app"
        });
        user.then(function(result) {
            emailUser = result.email;
            tokenUser = result.token1 + result.token2;
            db.close(test(emailUser, tokenUser));
        });
    });
}

function test(email, token){
        console.log(email);
//http://localhost:8080/rooms?email=""?token="" (IT HAS 2 PARAMS, EMAIL ADN USER TOKEN)
 frisby.create('Test DB').get('http://localhost:8080/rooms')
     .expectStatus(200)
     .toss();

 frisby.create('Test DB 2').get('http://localhost:8080/rooms')
     .expectStatus(200)
     .expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
     .toss();

 frisby.create('Creating Room: 09')
     .post('http://localhost:8080/rooms', {
         _id: "000000000000000000000002",
         number: 9,
         floor: 0
     })
     .expectStatus(200)
     .toss();
}

getDataUser();
```

The function test() should run after the db closes, but I'm getting the following result:

Finished in 0 seconds
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
Connected to Database
virtus-app@email.com

The test results should appear after my console.log outputs. I believe that the tests don't run and if they run, it is before I get the data.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into exactly the same problem with frisbyjs, there is a lack of BDD hooks like `before` and `after` for gathering data and clearing up anything created in the tests.

I ended up creating Chakram (https://github.com/dareid/chakram), which provides BDD hooks and utilises promises so that more complex tests can be easily written.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it.